How to set the width of vaadin charts tooltip?
I use Vaadin 24 and have created a customChart.css and imported it into my JavaScript class. I want to adjust the tooltip width for some of the charts.
Does anyone know how to do it?
Here is what I have done so far:
The chart in my litElementPage:
<div class="grams">
<vaadin-chart class="short-tooltip" id="chartYeBe" 
              @click=${e=>this.handleChartClick(e)}>
</vaadin-chart>

doChartsUpdate(mobile) {
        this.updateComplete.then(() => setTimeout(() =>
                this.charts.forEach(chart => {
                    const foundChart = chart.id === 'chartYeBe';
                    if (foundChart) {
                        if(mobile){
                            // How to set the tooltip width?
                            chart.configuration.tooltip.width = "50px";
                            
                        }
                    }                       
                }), 100)
            );
    }

I also tried this in the customChart.css but no effect
@media screen and (max-width:520px),screen and (max-width:932px) and (orientation:landscape) and (min-aspect-ratio:5/3) {
.highcharts-tooltip text, .highcharts-tooltip-box {
    width:70%;
}

:host([class="short-tooltip"]) #chartYeBe .highcharts-tooltip, .highcharts-tooltip-box {
    width: 70% !important; 
    white-space: normal !important; 
}
    
:host([class="short-tooltip"]) #chart .highcharts-tooltip, .highcharts-tooltip-box {
    width: 70% !important; 
    white-space: normal !important;
}

:host #chartYeBe .highcharts-tooltip, .highcharts-tooltip-box {
    width: 70% !important; 
    white-space: normal !important;
}

#chartYeBe .highcharts-tooltip, .highcharts-tooltip-box {
    width: 70% !important; 
    white-space: normal !important; 
}

}

You need to do a few things in order to make this work.
Setup the CSS to work with Vaadin Chart's shadow DOM:

Ensure your apps theme is setup correctly
Create vaadin-chart.css in frontend/themes/my-theme/components/ where 'my-theme' is the name of your apps theme
Add your CSS to vaadin-chart.css in the following format: :host .short-tooltip { /* rules here */ }

Configure the chart to use the CSS class:

Pass the required options into the <vaadin-chart> component via the .additionalOptions property:

Options.chart.styledMode: true
Options.tooltip.useHTML: true
Options.tooltip.formatter: function() { /* create tooltip and provide css classname */ }



Full Code Example:
frontend/themes/my-theme/components/vaadin-chart.css
:host .short-tooltip {
    /* css rules */
    width: 600px;
}

frontend/views/main-view.ts
import "@vaadin/charts";
import "highcharts/highcharts";

import { LitElement, html } from "lit";
import { customElement } from "lit/decorators.js";
import { Options } from "highcharts/highcharts";


@customElement("main-view")
export class MainLayout extends LitElement {

chartOptions: Options = {
  chart: {
      styledMode: true
  },
  tooltip: {
      useHTML: true,
      formatter: function() {
          // build the tooltip
          return '<div class="short-tooltip">' + this.y + '</div>'
      }
  }
};

  render() {
    return html`
      <div>

        <vaadin-chart type="pie" title="Pie Chart" tooltip .additionalOptions="${this.chartOptions}">
          <vaadin-chart-series
              title="My Chart"
              .values="${[
                { name: 'Adam', y: 22 },
                { name: 'Fred', y: 24 },
                { name: 'Bryan', y: 67 },
                { name: 'Sarah', y: 54 },
              ]}"
          >
          </vaadin-chart-series>
        </vaadin-chart>
        
      </div>
    `;
  }

}


Your styles need to be injected to the shadow DOM in order to work. If your theme in Vaadin is setup accroding to instructions, you should move your vaadin-chart styles under components folder and named with the same name as vaadin-chart tag.
frontend
└── themes
    └── my-theme
        ├── components
        |   └── vaadin-chart.css
        ├── styles.css
        └── theme.json

The tooltips and many other svg elements in vaadin-chart does not have part name defined as part selector is not yet supported in Chrome as we speak. CSS ::part selector doesn't work for SVG in Chrome
